# android 4.0 - Is there an API to configure the background data settings for a specific app

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In 4.0 the user has the ability to switchoff background data for an App.

Does the API provide any such functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, this isn't included as part of the Android SDK right now.

Once the ICS source code is released, you'll be able to look at the Samples app and see how this is done internally. At that point, I'd recommend opening up a feature request on [b.android.com](http://b.android.com) asking for this to be opened up as a public API.

Comment: Thanks Johns. The 4.0 feature list also has something related to  Disabling Apps in Android 4.0 :
Android Ice Cream Sandwich has a new feature that lets users disable practically any application they may want to, including those pesky carrier pre-installed apps that can strain device resources and drain battery even if you choose not to use them.